# Keras SIGSEGV (segfault) when adding LSTM in celery worker

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, segmentation-fault, celery

My celery worker crashes on this line:

```
model.add(LSTM(128))
```

and all I get is:

```
[2018-07-16 15:42:51,914: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:22365 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2018-07-16 15:42:51,942: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1223, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

The code works fine in a notebook I have done the following:

- Checked the installed versions of keras/tensorflow etc.
- Made all the keras imports happen at runtime (immediately above the crashing line)
- Made sure celery and rabbitmq are up to date

Mac OSX 10.13.5, High Sierra